# Is function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $h: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ Suppose now that we have two integrable functions $f$ and $g$. If now the integrals $$\int_0^t h(t-x) f'(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \quad \mbox{and} \quad \int_0^t h(t-x) g'(x)  \ \mathrm{d}x$$ both exist, can I conclude then that $h$ is differentiable?

Comment: FYI, the word you want is 'differentiable' not derivable.

Comment: What is $m$? What is $F$? Get a grip, mr_T!

Comment: upps sorry I wrong the false functions! thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and here is a simple counter-example: Let $f=g=x$ and let $h$ be a continuous nowhere differentiable function (e.g. the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)) then

$$F(t) = \int_0^t h(t-x) f'(x)dx= \int_0^t h(t-x) g'(x)dx = \int_0^t h(t-x)dx$$

exists since a continuous function is integrable.

Comment: Or you could let $f=g=0$ for maximum comfort.

Comment: @Thursday Lol. OP asks it this holds in general and this argument shows that this cannot be the case. There is no need for a more complex construction imo.